# How can I update RecyclerView in real time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list which can be updated any time by any user. The list is showed by in a **RecyclerView**. I want to update this list in real time so that user can get a better user experience because user need not to perform refresh several times. Now question is, how can I update this list in real time ?

Comment: Depends: Where does your data come from?

Comment: you can just call :             `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: data are coming from webservice. I have to update data first. How I will communicate with webservice in real time? Hadi Satrio

Comment: Communicating with the webservice and updating the RecyclerView are two different problems.  You will need a different strategy for retrieving the data.  The easiest way is to poll every x seconds, this can become a burden on webserver if there are many clients.  You can use long polling to keep a connection alive with the webserver, but that is not ideal for mobile clients.  Another way is to use push notifications to send only changed data.

Comment: If I poll every x seconds is there any issue about battery drain ? Gary Bak

Comment: @AliAhmed Did you have any solution for this? It will be helpful for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With RecyclerView you can either update a **single item, item range or the whole list** with the adapter.

You have to use `RecyclerView` adapter's method like `adapter#notifyItem***` or `adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()` (this will update the whole list of items in the RecyclerView).

```
class RVAdapter extends ...{ 
   List<?> itemList;

public void updateList (List<Object> items) {
        if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
            itemList.clear();
            itemList.addAll(items);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But data are coming from webservice. I have to update data first. How I will communicate with webservice in real time?

Comment: you must be parsing data and storing in a List<?>. So you can swap the List<?> passed to the RecyclerView with the new List<?> which you have obtained from webservice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create metod inside your Adapter which updates the data and refreshes ur recyclerview.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
   List<Data> data;
   ...

 public void update(ArrayList<Data> datas){
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(datas);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
    ...
}
```

Just call the update method passing new data. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call same set recycler adapter code.
do not forget to call `adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`