# How can I update certain values in recyclerview whenever onMessage function called?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making an android app and facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039501/how-can-i-update-recyclerview-in-real-time) similar issue I am sending data my SQL server using FCM which received in onMessage function in my app, but at the time of receiving the data I am not sure weather that specific screen exist or not? maybe user was on another screen at that time.
And along with this there will be number of different data objects for different screens? How can I make sure that data will properly update the existing data I know how to update data so please don't think about that, problem is how to call update functions of different screen which may or may not exist at that time.

I have spent more than 3 days on this solution but can't figure out. Please any good suggestion could prove a lot of help.

Comment: so you need to check which screen is open at a time of notification arrives?

Comment: yeah that screen and also the the way of updating recycler items without scrolling the list because dataSetChanged() function change the scroll position. @Divyesh

Comment: u can use process manger to detect which activity is currently running. and data arrives use notifyiteminserted()

Comment: you mean activity manager ???? I tried that too but don't know where should I store data of other screens ??? Should I always create local db for it ?

Comment: there is method to check if app is in background or in foreground. in that place your activity name and place whole code in onmessage () method

Comment: Also tell me is it right approach to solve such kind of issues ??? or there are predefined SOP's for it ?

Comment: you have to create your own logig , not predefine method for think as far as i know

Comment: @Divyesh thanks a lot I will keep in mind your suggestion